# How can I terminate program running continuously via rc.local?

Tags: raspbian, boot

I edited the /etc/rc.local to run a python script. It works, but it never ends, I tried Ctrl+c but it does not work I can't get in to the log in / password display.

Comment: That would be because you forgot the trailing `&` to run the python script in the background whilst the rest of the `/etc/rc.local` was run and then exited wouldn't it? 8-)  Most of the answers that I can see below seem to think that `/etc/rc.local` has finished (so that then the RPi proceeds to complete multi-user start-up) - but you need to avoid `rc.local` from being run...

Answer (score 1):

Try ctrl+alt+f1 to get a console window (ctrl+alt+f7 to return).

You can login and edit/kill the script and reboot.

Search for password recovery.

Alternatively edit cmdline.txt (it's on a FAT partition so is visible on a Windows machine) and add init=/bin/sh to the end of the (single) line.  Reboot and edit rc.local then undo the change to cmdline.txt and reboot again.

Comment: it doen´t work, ctrl+alt+f4 f5 f6 turns black the screen with ctrl+alt+f1 im returning to the script

Comment: @Wilty Added an aleternative to post.

Comment: Also, once you get to a regular state again, make sure the last line in /etc/rc.local is `exit 0`.

Comment: i also try with the cmdline stuff with the recover because, i didnt see the cmdline.txt on windows :S

Comment: @Wilty If you are using NOOBS you'll need to google a bit more.  I don't know what to do when using NOOBS.

Answer (score 1):

If all fails:

a) If you are using NOOBS hold shift at startup and you can restore

b) Plug the card into an alternate computer, pull off the files you want, and wipe/reinstall

Answer (score 1):

When booting to CLI, alt+print+k seems to work. This kills all processes running in the current terminal, from what i read. You get to the CLI then, and can modify rc.local.

Comment: You mean the [magic `sys-req` key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)?

Comment: Thanks for the link for background info =) Didn't know this key combination is part of a whole set oO

Answer (score 0):

try putting a background process  in `rc.local`

```
!/usr/bin/sh
runMyScript() {
    python PATH/TO/SCRIPT/script.py &
}
runMyScript
```

Next time you reboot your Pi you will get your **login** again